# How to stack a transparent image on another image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Wanted to have two images where i have a mask stacked on top of another image. But in doing so, i wish to not have two images blend together, rather have the final image stacked onto each other like layers

**Here's my original images**

[image]

[image]

**masked image**

[image]

**code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('test72.jpg')

image2 = cv2.imread('test63.jpg')

blank = np.full((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3), (255,255,255), np.uint8)

circle = cv2.circle(blank, (300,300), 10, (0, 0, 0), thickness= 100)

blur = cv2.blur(circle, (50, 50), 0)

subtract = cv2.subtract(image, blur)

blended = cv2.addWeighted(image2, 1, subtract, 1, 0)


cv2.imwrite('mask.jpg', subtract)
cv2.imwrite('blend.jpg', blended)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is what the result looks like when the function cv2.addweighted is added, which results in the bannanas blending in the shoes, is there another function in OpenCv i could do to make this stack rather than blend?

[image]

Comment: Can you mock up the desired result in Photoshop or GIMP so we know what to aim for, please? One person's *"stack"* is another person's "*merge"* is another person's *"blend"* is another person's *"smush"*....

Comment: @MarkSetchell perhaps what he wants is to show banana inside the shoes uncensored (no pun intended :D )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work in your case:

```
im1_alpha = blur/255
im2_alpha = (255-blur)/255

out_img = ((image2 * im1_alpha) + (image * im2_alpha)).astype(np.uint8)
plt.imshow(out_img)
```

Comment: If you look carefully at this solution and compare it with the one you posted, they are both exactly the same, except that you are using opencv functions like multiply and add. My code is doing all those operations in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer!
I followed this tutorial right here! [Alpha blending tutorial right here](https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('test72.jpg')

image2 = cv2.imread('test63.jpg')

blank = np.full((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3), (255,255,255), np.uint8)

circle = cv2.circle(blank, (300,350), 10, (0, 0, 0), thickness= 100)

blur = cv2.blur(circle, (50, 50), 0)

image = image.astype(float)

image2 = image2.astype(float)

alpha = blur.astype(float)/255

multiply = cv2.multiply(alpha, image2)

multiply2 = cv2.multiply(1.0 - alpha, image)

add = cv2.add(multiply, multiply2).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('alpha', add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```